# detect volume button press in android 12

Tags: android, android-12, android-13

im able to successfully detect volume button press when my App activity is open and active. Id like to be able to detect the key press also when my app activity is closed. Can anyone let me know if this is possible?

Because of the restrictions on Foreground services in android 12, i think this is not possible via a foreground service.

Comment: did you find a solution for android 12+?

Comment: yes, But i had to do it via Foreground service

Comment: yeah, of course it should be a foreground service, can you answer here to your question with an example?